# C# SortedDictionary ContainsKey returns false even though key exists

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

This is how I create my SortedDictionary:

```
protected class OccupiedComparer : IComparer<Structure>
{
    public int Compare(Structure a, Structure b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return 0;

        if (a.AtomicPosition.x > b.AtomicPosition.x)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}

protected SortedDictionary<Structure, Vector2> m_BuildingOccupied = new SortedDictionary<Structure, Vector2>(new OccupiedComparer());
```

I run this code:

```
m_BuildingOccupied.Add(s, new Vector2(x, y));
foreach (var k in m_BuildingOccupied.Keys) {
    bool c = m_BuildingOccupied.ContainsKey(k);
    int hs = k.GetHashCode();
    Debug.Log(hs + ", " + c);
}
```

And even though all added keys are printed to the console, some of them have "c" equal to false, which means that ContainsKey returned false.. Even though the key obviously is present in the dictionary.

Any idea what could be the cause of this problem? My custom comparer, perhaps?

Comment: Your comparer is mixing reference equality and value equality.   Specifically if you have two `Structure` objects with the same `AtomicPosition.x` value they are not treated as being equal.  That's bad because `Compare(a,b)` and `Compare(b,a)` would both return -1.

Comment: How comes? I do: if(a == b) return 0, so it should return 0 if two objects are the same before even looking at atomic position

Comment: Because `a == b` is doing a reference comparison (unless you've actually verloaded the == operator for `Structure`).  It seems like your comparer should just be `return a.AtomicPosition.x.CompareTo(b.AtomicPosition.x);`

Comment: Why not add a conditional break point in your compare for one of the Keys that's not being found and see what it does?

Comment: @kamac `a == b` if they are the same object only, not if they have the same `AtomicPosition.x`.  So when the dictionary tries to sort two different `Structure` objects with the same `AtomicPosition.x` it's going to always think the first one is less than the second even if you swap them.  Basically you'll have a < b and b < a both being true which ultimately will screw up the sorting.

Comment: @Peter4499 apparently ContainsKey goes into my custom Comparer's *Compare* function, but only once, and it compares my *k* with some other random key...

Comment: @juharr There never are two different structure objects with the same AtomicPosition.x

Comment: @kamac when you say "random" key, is it still a structure or does it look like `k.GetHashCode()`?

Comment: @Peter4499 it's still a structure, but it seems like it's a random key from m_BuildingOccupied

Comment: @kamac can you share the implementation of == on Structure? or better yet change ` if (a == b)
            return 0;` to `if (a.AtomicPosition.x == b.AtomicPosition.x) return 0`

Comment: @Peter4499 I can't share the implementation of == on Structure, because I don't have it. Blame Unity. But I've made HashSet that contains Structures, and I add and remove to it whenever I add/remove to m_BuildingOccupied, but it always contains the searched element, unlike SortedDictionary which sometimes returns false on elements it should contain. Even if I do a.AtomicPosition.x == b.AtomicPosition.x it doesn't explain why it doesn't work, but I have a theory - maybe AtomicPosition.x somehow changes without my knowledge, resulting in dictionary being sorted incorrectly = not finding the key

Comment: @Peter4499 I've checked now, but it doesn't seem like AtomicPosition.x is changing. Nevertheless, I am getting object with different hashcode than what I was searching for, suggesting there is something fishy going on

Comment: @kamac if `a.AtomicPosition.x == b.Atomic.Position.x` works then it points towards an issue with == implementation of structure, that's why I was asking that. Since according to your comments Atomic Position can't be the same, then the only time that a..x will == b..x is when it's the same object being compared.

Comment: @kamac I'm guessing that a new instance of structure is created but it's assigned the same instance of AtomicPosition. Try checking the Hash for AtomicPosition, I'm betting they'll all match.

Comment: @Peter4499 actually there is a very short moment during which there are two structures with exactly same X position, but I can't get around it very easily. Welp. I might just switch to a List, and sort stuff myself.

Answer (score -1):

the default operator == compares references of classes

solution:

Overload Equals and GetHashcode()
or compare all the fields instead.

Comment: `a == b` and `a.Equals(b)` will be the same unless `==` is overloaded for `Structure` or `Equals` is overridden for `Structure` and if both are then it's possible they would still give the same result.

Comment: No, for structres they operate differently, Equals compare all the fields of the object will == isnt

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz *Structure* is a class, it's only named *Structure*

Comment: ahh didnt know, sorry

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz Because it's a class that represents a building, or a torch or any "structure"